# AWS Amplify Lambda with shared custom modules (python)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I'm working on an Amplify project which is supposed to contain three or four different python-written Lambda function;

as I'm realizing that the functions share a relevant amount of lines of code, I was wondering what would be the proper/easiest way to proceed in order to extract the common required features between the lambdas in a module (possibly internal to the project) and make it accessible to all the lambdas in the project which requires it, respecting as much as possible the standart amplify workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way is to extract the common code in lambda layers and use those lambda layers in different lambda functions. Find the below documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

From the documentation - "Layers promote code sharing and separation of responsibilities so that you can iterate faster on writing business logic."

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer and sorry for my late response; the main issues with working with layers in this context is that I am working with amplify (which provide an easy way to create layers from existing third part open source library, idk about selfmade modules) so updating lambdas and dependencies is more a matter of 'amplify add function', 'amplify push' than manually uploading zip file from the console (which I understand is how you are proposing to solve the situation). Am I missing something of your solution that would make it suitable for my situation?